# Problem matching single digits when integers are defined as tokens

Tags: antlr4

I'm having problem trying to get a grammar working. Here is the simplified version. The language I try to parse has expressions like these:

```
testing1(2342);
testing2(idfor2);
testing3(4654);
testing4[1..n];
testing5[0..1];
testing6(7);
testing7(1);
testing8(o);
testing9(n);
```

The problem arises when I introduce the rules for the [1..n] or [0..1] expressions. The grammar file (one of the many variations I've tried):

```
grammar test;

tests
    : test* ;

test
    : call
    | declaration ;

call
    : callName '(' callParameter ')' ';' ;

callName : Identifier ;

callParameter : Identifier | Integer ;

declaration
    : declarationName '[' declarationParams ']' ';' ;

declarationName : Identifier ;


declarationParams
    : decMin '..' decMax ;

decMin : '0' | '1' ;
decMax : '1' | 'n' ;

Integer : [0-9]+ ;
Identifier : [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]* ;

WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

When I parse the sample with this grammar, it fails on `testing7(1);` and `testint(9);`. It matches as `decMin` or `decMax` instead of `Integer` or `Identifier`:

```
line 8:9 mismatched input '1' expecting {Integer, Identifier}
line 10:9 mismatched input 'n' expecting {Integer, Identifier}
```

I've tried many variations but I can't make it work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem comes from not using **lexer rules** clearly defining what you want.

When you added this rule :

```
decMin : '0' | '1' ;
```

You in fact created an **unnamed lexer rule** that matches '0' and another one matching '1' :

```
UNNAMED_0_RULE : '0';
UNNAMED_1_RULE : '1';
```

And your parser rule became :

```
decMin : UNNAMED_0_RULE | UNNAMED_1_RULE ;
```

Problem : now, when your lexer see
*testing7(1);*
**it doesn't see **
*callName '(' callParameter ')' ';'*
anymore, it sees
*callName '(' UNNAMED_1_RULE ')' ';'*
and it doesn't understand that.

And that is because lexer rules are effective before the parser rules.

To solve your problem, define your lexer rules efficiently, It would probably look like that :

```
grammar test;

/*---------------- PARSER ----------------*/
tests
    : test* 
    ;

test
    : call
    | declaration 
    ;


call
    : callName '(' callParameter ')' ';' 
    ;

callName 
    : identifier 
    ;

callParameter 
    : identifier 
    | integer 
    ;


declaration
    : declarationName '[' declarationParams ']' ';' 
    ;

declarationName 
    : identifier 
    ;

declarationParams
    : decMin '..' decMax 
    ;


decMin 
    : INTEGER_ZERO 
    | INTEGER_ONE
    ;

decMax 
    : INTEGER_ONE
    | LETTER_N
    ;

integer 
    : (INTEGER_ZERO | INTEGER_ONE | INTEGER_OTHERS)+
    ;

identifier
    : LETTER_N
    | IDENTIFIER
    ;

/*---------------- LEXER ----------------*/

LETTER_N:       N;

IDENTIFIER 
    : [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*
    ;

WS
    : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip 
    ;

INTEGER_ZERO:   '0';
INTEGER_ONE:    '1';
INTEGER_OTHERS: '2'..'9';

fragment N: [nN];
```

I just tested this grammar and **it works**.

The drawback is that it will cut your integers at the lexer step (cutting 1245 into 1 2 4 5 in lexer rules, and the considering the parser rule as uniting 1 2 4 and 5).

I think it would be better to be less precise and simply write :
decMin: integer | identifier;

But then it depends on what you do with your grammar...

Comment: Yes! It works now. I've tried something so before, but what makes the real difference is to convert `Identifier` and `Integer` to rules instead of lexemes.